# Is there a way to graph glm in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to graph a glm.nb model that I have. However, I'm not sure if there are too many variables in the model or if this is even possible. The first three (c, d, e) are being used to account for the variation between populations. There weren't enough levels to use populations as a random factor so I had to include them this way. But this is complicating how I try to graph. I also would like two lines, differentiated by the species.

This is the model I want to graph.

```
model1<- glm(distance~speed+species+c+d+e, data=data)
```

I tried using `qplot` at first but then I realized this wasn't based on the actual model, including the populations.

```
qplot(x = speed, y = distance, data = data, color = species) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=species),method = "lm")
```

Then I tried to include the equation but I don't think the graph was accurate.

```
equation1=equation1=function(x){coef(model1)[2]*x+coef(model1)[1]}
equation2=function(x){coef(model1)[2]*x+coef(model1)[1]+coef(model1)[3]}

ggplot(data, aes(y=distance,x=speed,color=species), geom_smooth(aes(group=species),method = "lm") )+geom_point()+
  stat_function(fun=equation1,geom="line",color=scales::hue_pal()(2)[1])+
  stat_function(fun=equation2,geom="line",color=scales::hue_pal()(2)[2])
```

Comment: You need to `predict(model1)` and save the output in either the same data frame or a new one. Then you will plot the new data set.

Comment: after I predict, can I use that new data frame in ggplot?

Comment: Yes, you're definitely over-complicating it above.